# A-frame sound : How to react to the end of the sound?

Tags: javascript, events, audio, aframe

Loop false, poolsize 1.

Running sound.playSound() successfully plays the sound, but sound.isPlaying remains true even after the full sound has been played.

Already tried adding the 'sound-ended' event listener on the entity but it doesn't trigger neither.

There must be a proper state somewhere... right ?

Comment: `sound.isPlaying remains true even after the full sound has been played.` you're probably doing it wrong then - or perhaps a-frame is getting it wrong

Comment: You're running `playSound()` on the `sound` component, or `audio` node?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski : playSound() on the sound component of an entity that only hold the sound component.
I've just noticed that isPlaying is actually a boolean of the entity 'class', that could explain why it's not what i was expecting.

Comment: not sure why `isPlaying` won't change, looks like a bug, you can still listen for events to keep track of what's going on

Answer (score 1):

You can track the state of the `sound` component by listening to the `sound-ended` event. Below, click the button to play a sound, it will remain red until the audio track is over.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      const soundComp = this.el.components.sound; // grab the `sound` component
       
      // play the sound when the user clicks the button
      this.el.addEventListener("click", evt => {               
        this.el.setAttribute("color", "red") // turn the button red
        soundComp.playSound(); // playsound
      })

      // catch the `sound-ended` event
      this.el.addEventListener("sound-ended", evt => {
        this.el.setAttribute("color", "green") // turn it back to green
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: a-sphere">
  <a-assets>
    <audio id="ding" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/sound/sound/Ding-sound-effect.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  </a-assets>
  <a-sphere position="0 1 -3" radius="0.25" color="green" sound="src: #ding; autoplay: false" foo ></a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr, that's usefull because this snippet does not work for me, but it just did for my friend. I'm using Firefox 102 and he's using Chrome.

Comment: wow, i have no idea why the sound isn't loading on firefox, ill look into it.

Comment: So far i've tried overriding the sound.onEnded callback and put some console.log inside it. It's not triggered in my tests.

Comment: From what i see, the file is partially loaded (206) and it's considered to be an error ([glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/harvest-innovative-lemming?path=index.html%3A23%3A0) - I've copied the sound component to throw in a bit more logs).